Testing request timeout in C# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API locally
I'm attempting to test request timeout functionality in a C# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API on my local environment.
Here's my setup: in Program.cs, I've configured middleware using AddRequestTimeouts and UseRequestTimeouts. I've defined a default policy and an additional policy named ThreeSecondsPolicy. I've set Timeout, TimeoutStatusCode, and WriteTimeoutResponse properties for both policies.
Here's a snippet of the relevant code from Program.cs:
    builder.Services.AddRequestTimeouts(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new RequestTimeoutPolicy 
        { 
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            TimeoutStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
            WriteTimeoutResponse = async (HttpContext context) =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Timeout from Default Policy!");
            }
        };

        options.AddPolicy("ThreeSecondsPolicy", new RequestTimeoutPolicy
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000),
            TimeoutStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
            WriteTimeoutResponse = async (HttpContext context) =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Timeout from ThreeSecondsPolicy!");
            }
        });
    });

    app.UseRequestTimeouts();

In my controller method, annotated with [RequestTimeout(policyName: "ThreeSecondsPolicy")]
Here's a snippet of the controller and service method:
    [Route("/details")]
    [HttpGet]
    [RequestTimeout(policyName: "ThreeSecondsPolicy")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<StudentResponse>> GetstudentDetails([Required, FromQuery] string studentId)
    {
        try
        {
            StudentResponse StudentResponse = await factory.Service.ExecuteStudentDetails(studentId, HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            if (StudentResponse != null && StudentResponse.studentDetails != null)
            {
                if (StudentResponse.studentDetails.Any())
                {
                    StudentResponse.ActionResult = new StudentDetailsActionResult { Code = HttpStatusCode.OK, Messages = new List<string> { "Success" } };
                    return Ok(StudentResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    LogException(HttpStatusCode.OK, new List<string> { "Empty result" });
                    StudentResponse = new StudentResponse
                    {
                        ActionResult = new StudentDetailsActionResult { Code = HttpStatusCode.OK, Messages = new List<string> { "Empty result" } }
                    };
                    return StatusCode(200, StudentResponse);
                }
            }       
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new List<string> { ex.ToString() });
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public async Task<StudentResponse> ExecuteStudentDetails( string id, CancellationToken token)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        try
        {
            var studentData = await dataAccessHelper.GetStudentData(id);
            StudentResponseMapper studentResponseMapper = factory.CreateStudentResMapper();
            var data = studentResponseMapper.MapResponse(studentData);
            return data;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Return a custom response indicating a request timeout (408 status code with a custom message)
            var timeoutResponse = new StudentResponse
            {
                // You can customize the response message as needed
                ActionResult = new StudentDetailsActionResult
                {
                    Code = HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
                    Messages = new List<string> { "Request timed out" }
                }
            };

            return timeoutResponse;
        }
    }

I'm running the application without the debugger attached, as recommended by Microsoft's documentation.
While testing, I'm observing the following:

Timeout functionality is working as expected in Postman.
However, I'm not receiving the expected status code 408 or the custom message set in WriteTimeoutResponse property in Program.cs.

How can I resolve these issues and accurately get status code with custom message?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Hi @Sumit, for better resolving your issue, could you pls share the code instead of screenshot?

Hi @Rena, just added the code.

The use of "UseRequestTimeouts()" only sets HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested = true. You need to handle the timeout before "return OK()" by using "HttpContext.RequestAborted.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();"

Double check that you don't have an ExceptionFilter configured on your controllers. This would intercept any exception before it can be handled by RequestTimeoutsMiddleware that uses the TimeoutStatusCode and WriteTimeoutResponse.
